# JQuery click eventhandler: register event on dynamically added element

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, dynamic, hyperlink

I would like to dynamically build a page from 2 hashes (in my example c and d).

```
var c = { 
  cluster_1 : { list_datasets: [ "a", "b", "c"]},
  cluster_2 : { list_datasets: [ "b", "c"]},
};
var d = {
  a : { title: "A", content: "aaaaaaaaaaaaaa"},
  b : { title: "B", content: "bbbbbbbbbbbbbb"},
  c : { title: "C", content: "cccccccccccccc"},  
};
```

so that I first get the list of clusters, and then by clicking on the cluster, I get the list of their respective content. This works fine until here.

But now if I want to go a step further end by clicking on each dataset, I would like to have the dataset description. The jquery selection operation $('#a') is empty and nothing is shown.  [Here a little standalone example that shows the problem](http://jsfiddle.net/HTUzh/3)

Thanks a lot for you help or any information on that topic.

Kind regards

Antoine

Comment: sorry, the given example was not complete. Here the right example : http://jsfiddle.net/HTUzh/3/

Comment: `JQuery click eventhandler: register event on dynamically added element`-> jQuery `.delegate()` (or `.on()`, but confusing imo)

Answer (score 0):

Since these elements are created dynamically, you have to use **`delegate`** event handler like

```
 $(document).on('click', '#'+key, function(event){
        $("aside").html(value.content);
      });
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_jegan/HTUzh/4/)

Comment: Thanks a lot, 

The delegate event handler has solved the problem. Here the little code snippet with this time the right way to do add eventhandler on dynamically generated elements : http://jsfiddle.net/HTUzh/7/

kind regards

Antoine

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you call second each

> $.each(d, function(key, value){ ..

when there are no elements printed on the page.
Elements get printed only when you click on any of clusters. So you should wrap second each with a function e.g.

```
    function getValues(){    
$.each(d, function(key, value){
  $('#' + key).each(function(){

    console.log(value.content);

  });

});
};
```

and call it at the end of click function

```
 $('#' + cluster).click(function( event ) {

    var content_list = "<ul>";

    for (var i = 0; i < value.list_datasets.length; i++) {

      var dsName = datasetName = value.list_datasets[i];

      if(d.hasOwnProperty( datasetName ) ) {
        var datasetName = d[datasetName].title;

      }

      content_list = content_list + "<li><a id='" + dsName + "' href='#foo'>" +  datasetName + "</a></li>";
    }

    content_list = content_list + "</ul>";

    $("section").html(content_list);
  getValues();
  });
```